# Remove url strings from series

Tags: python, nlp

I have a function to remove url links from a series, but it doesn't appear to work. The error when I pass the series through the function is: 'str' object has no attribute 're'

```
def remove_url(list_of_tokens):
    '''
    Remove url
    ''' 

    cleaned_tokens = [] 

    for token in list_of_tokens: 
        token = token.re.sub(r"http\S+", "")
        cleaned_tokens.append(token)

    return cleaned_tokens
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.sub` takes the following parameters:

`re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

where `pattern` is the pattern to search for, `repl` is what matches should be replaced with, and `string` is the string to be operated on. Thus your solution should look like this:

```
token = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't call it on the string. You call re.sub() with the required paramters passed to the function. Import re also.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

```
>> re.sub(r'\sAND\s', ' & ', 'Baked Beans And Spam', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
Baked Beans & Spam
```